# Symmetrical Lerp & compiler optimizations

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, numerical-stability, lerp

I had a function:

```
float lerp(float alpha, float x0, float x1) {
    return (1.0f - alpha) * x0 + alpha * x1;
}
```

For those who haven't seen it, this is preferable to `x0 + (x1-x0)
 * alpha` because the latter doesn't guarantee that `lerp(1.0f, x0, x1) == x1`.

Now, I want my `lerp` function to have an additional property: I'd like `lerp(alpha, x0, x1) == lerp(1-alpha, x1, x0)`. (As for why: this is a toy example of a more complicated function.) The solution I came up with that seems to work is

```
float lerp_symmetric(float alpha, float x0, float x1) {
    float w0 = 1.0f - alpha;
    float w1 = 1.0f - w0;
    return w0 * x0 + w1 * x1;
}
```

This double subtraction has the effect of rounding near zero and near one, so if `alpha = std::nextafter(0)` (1.4012985e-45), then `1 - alpha == 1` and so `1 - (1-alpha) == 0`. As far as I can tell, it is always true that `1.0f - x == 1.0f - (1.0f - (1.0f - x))`. It also seems to have the effect that `w0 + w1 == 1.0f`.

Questions:

1. Is this a reasonable approach?
2. Can I trust my compiler to do what I want? In particular, I know on Windows it sometimes uses more precision for partial results, and I know the compiler is allowed to do some algebra; obviously 1-(1-x)==x algebraically.

This is in C++11 using Clang, VisualStudio, and gcc.

Comment: What language? C, C++, or something else? Any particular compilers?

Comment: I believe your additional property is satisfied if IEEE-754 arithmetic of `float` precision is used throughout. C and C++ allow `w0*x0 + w1*x1` to be evaluated flexibly. You can somewhat defeat that by writing `t0 = w0*x0; t1 = w1*x1; return t0+t1;`, as assignments must discard excess precision. Then the language rules still allow `t0 = x0*x0`, for example, to be computed with excess precision and then narrowed to `float`. However, I believe there is a paper stating this is equivalent to computing in `float` provided the excess precision is sufficiently large.

Comment: Do you have references for that? Where do I find these rules?

Comment: Rules for the programming language as in [the language standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).

Comment: You should add the C++ tag. That requires removing one of the others, since the limit is five. The optimization tag is probably the least applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one format of IEEE-754 binary floating-point is used throughout (e.g., basic 32-bit binary, the format commonly used for C++ `float`), with all C++ operators mapped to IEEE-754 operations in the direct and simple way, then `lerp_symmetric(alpha, x0, x1)` (hereafter referred to as `A`) equals `lerp_symmetric(1-alpha, x1, x0)` (`B`)

Proof:

- If `alpha`, which we assume is in [0, 1], is greater than or equal to ½, then `1-alpha` is exact by Sterbenz’ lemma. (By “exact,” we mean the computed floating-point result equals the mathematical resulting; there is no rounding error.) Then, in computing `A`, `w0` is exact since it is `1-alpha`, and `w1` is exact since its mathematical result is `alpha`, so it is exactly representable. And, in computing `B`, `w0` is exact since its mathematical result is `alpha`, and `w1` is exact since it is again `1-alpha`.
- If `alpha` is less than ½, then `1-alpha` may have some rounding error. Let the result be `beta`. Then, in `A`, `w0` is `beta`. Now ½ ≤ `beta`, so Sterbenz’ lemma applies to the evaluation of `w1 = 1.0f - w0`, so `w1` is exact (and equals the mathematical result of `1-beta`). And, in `B`, `w0` is exact, again by Sterbenz' lemma, and equals the `w1` of `A`, and `w1` (of `B`) is exact since its mathematical result is `beta`, which is exactly representable.

Now we can see that `w0` in `A` equals `w1` in `B` and `w1` in `A` equals `w0` in `B`. Letting `beta` be `1-alpha` in either of the above cases, `A` and `B` therefore return `(1-beta)*x0 + beta*x1` and `beta*x1 + (1-beta)*x0`, respectively. IEEE-754 addition is commutative (except for NaN payloads), so `A` and `B` return identical results.

Answering the questions:

1. I would say it is a reasonable approach. Without further thought, I would not assert there are not improvements that could be made.
2. No, you cannot trust your compiler:

- C++ allows implementations to use excess precision when evaluating floating-point arithmetic. Thus `w0*x0 + w1*x1` may be evaluated using `double`, `long double`, or another precision even though all operands are `float`.
- C++ allows contractions unless disabled, so `w0*x0 + w1*x1` may be evaluated as `fmaf(w0, x0, w1*x1)`, thus using exact arithmetic for one of the multiplications but not the other.

You can partially work around this by using:

```
float w0 = 1.0f - alpha;
float w1 = 1.0f - w0;
float t0 = w0*x0;
float t1 = w1*x1;
return t0+t1;
```

The C++ standard requires that excess precision be discarded in assignments and casts. This extends to function returns. (I report this and other C++ specifications from memory; the standard should be checked.) So each of the above will round its result to `float` even if extra precision was initially used. This will prevent contraction.

(One should also be able to disable contraction by including `<cmath>` and inserting the preprocessor directive `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT OFF`. Some compilers might not support that.)

One problem with the workaround above is that values are first rounded to the evaluation precision and then rounded to `float`. There are mathematical values for which, for such a value *x*, rounding *x* first to `double` (or another precision) and then to `float` produces a different result than rounding *x* directly to `float`. The dissertation *A Rigorous Framework for Fully Supporting the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic in High-Level Programming Languages* by Samuel A. Figueroa del Cid establishes that evaluating a single operation of multiplication or addition in IEEE-754 basic 64-bit floating-point (commonly used for `double`) and then rounding to the 32-bit format never has a double-rounding error (because these operations, given inputs that are elements of the 32-bit format, can never produce one of the troublesome *x* values described above).<sup>1</sup>

If I am correct about the C++ specifications reported from memory, then the workaround describe above should be complete as long as the C++ implementation evaluates floating-point expressions either with the nominal format or with a format sufficiently wider to satisfy the requirements Figueroa del Cid gives.

## Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Per Figueroa del Cid, if `x` and `y` have *p*-bit significands, and `x+y` or `x*y` is computed exactly and then rounded to *q* places, a second rounding to *p* places will have the same answer as if the result were directly rounded to *p* places if *p* ≤ (*q* − *1*)/2. This is satisfied for IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point (*p* = 24) and 64-bit (*q* = 53). These formats are commonly used for `float` and `double`, and the workaround above should suffice in a C++ implementation that uses them. If a C++ implementation evaluated `float` using a precision that did not satisfy the condition Figueroa del Cid gives, then double-rounding errors could occur.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know about Sterbenz’ lemma, `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT off`, and `fma`, among other things.